# How to use contexts in MagicalRecord version >= 2.0?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

i'm having problems with using MagicalRecord correctly; when to use MR_save vs. MR_saveNestedContexts? The latter seems the better choice:

> This means that it may be necessary to use MR_saveNestedContexts rather than the typical MR_save method in order to persist your changes all the way to your persistent store

But some of the saving is happening asynchronously, so I don't know if that fits every use case.

Also - how to read, change and save data, especially in the background? With the default context, contextForCurrentThread?

Are there some rules when to use which context (default vs contextForCurrentThread) when reading, editing, saving as well as which save method is to be used when?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the most success using the `MR_saveWithBlock:` and `MR_saveWithBlockAndWait:` methods. The only gotcha is that if you are using a NSManagedObject from a different context/thread in the block you will want to grab a version of it in the local context using the `MR_inContext:` method.